# Prove two polynomials are equal

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

define$$f^{-1}(a)=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:f(z)=a\}$$
$f$ and $g$ are polynomials,
$$f^{-1}(0)=g^{-1}(0) ,f^{-1}(1)=g^{-1}(1)$$ prove $f=g$

I wonder if there is a complex analysis way to solve it?

Comment: If $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^3$, then $f^{-1}(x)=x$ and $g^{-1}(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$. These are not equal, yet your theorem says they are.

Comment: @KristofferRyhl: In your example, $f^{-1}(1) = \{1 \}$ and $g^{-1}(1)$ is the set of the three third roots of unity, so the sets are not equal.

Comment: @KristofferRyhl I didn't make it clearly , I mean in complex plane

Answer (score 1):

You can assume that $n = \deg f \ge \deg g > 0$. Then $h = (f-g)f'$ is a polynomial of degree $\le 2n-1$. Furthermore, any zero of multiplicity $m \ge 1$ of $f$ is a zero of multiplicity $m-1$ of $f'$, and it is at least a simple zero of $f-g$, so it is a zero of multiplicity $\ge m$ of $h$. This shows that $f$ divides $h$. The same argument also shows that $f-1$ divides $h$. Since $f$ and $f-1$ are relatively prime polynomials, this implies that $f(f-1)$ divides $h$. However, the degree of $f(f-1)$ is $2n$, which is larger than the degree of $h$, so $h \equiv 0$.